# Yesod - Integrating Yesod-Auth-Account 1.4.3 with the scaffolding site

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, yesod

I am trying to use Account authentication plugin of Yesod in the scaffolding site. The scaffolding site on its own works fine and plugin on its own works fine, however, when I try to integrate the plugin in the project either through by adding the extra dependency in the stack.yaml file (i.e. (extra-deps: [yesod-auth-account-1.4.3]) or without adding the dependency where I have to  make a lot of changes in my project, in both cases stack build fails with the following error coming from the Account.hs file:

```
Couldn't match type ‘UserAccount db0’ with ‘UserAccount db’
      Expected type: UserAccount db
                     -> HandlerT Auth (HandlerT master IO) Html
        Actual type: UserAccount db0
                     -> HandlerT Auth (HandlerT master0 IO) Html
      NB: ‘UserAccount’ is a type function, and may not be injective
      The type variable ‘db0’ is ambiguous
    • In the ambiguity check for ‘unregisteredLogin’
      To defer the ambiguity check to use sites, enable AllowAmbiguousTypes
      When checking the class method:
        unregisteredLogin :: forall (db :: * -> *) master.
                             YesodAuthAccount db master =>
                             UserAccount db -> HandlerT Auth (HandlerT master IO) Html
      In the class declaration for ‘YesodAuthAccount’
    |
806 |     unregisteredLogin :: UserAccount db -> HandlerT Auth (HandlerT master IO) Html
    |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I have seen some solutions online regarding adding "liftHandler ." for each runDB action and using "Proxy master", however they do not seem to work.

My guess here is that there is a database conflict in the project, as the scaffolding site uses a sample database for dummy login which is not recommended for production version. As a result, I am looking for an efficient authentication plugin.

Any type of help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.